# How to display dynamical content from a remote file in bootstrap modal using php?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have following table that shows some info and calls a remote modal box.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Family Name</td>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Lennon</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="remote.php">OK</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>Joey</td>
        <td>Ramone</td>
        <td>US</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="remote.php">OK</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Satriani</td>
        <td>US</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="remote.php">OK</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here my modal code:

```
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->

    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</div> 

<!-- /.Modal -->
```

I would like to know how I could send the info that appears inside the cells (td) of any line (tr) to the remote file (remote.php) where a php script would run with this info and give us an output that would be showed in the modal without to refresh the page.

Before that I used to send by POST the info with a form:
(I show here only the cell with the form. The rest is the same).

```
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td>
            <form id="form" action="remote.php" method="POST">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="01" />
                <input name="name" type="hidden" value="Jonh" />
                <input name="family" type="hidden" value="Lennon" />
                <input name="country" type="hidden" value="UK" />
                <input type="submit" value="OK">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

After the script ran it was redirect back to the page and the modal was shown. That's what I would like to avoid.

Until now I'm able to show the content of the remote file in the modal. But it's a static content. Does anybody have an idea how can I send the info (variables) of the table to the remote file dynamically with this modal structure?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the `remote` option is deprecated in version <kbd>3.3.0</kbd> and will be removed in version  <kbd>4</kbd>, you would have to manage loading of the remote content yourself. I would suggest the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>03</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Satriani</td>
    <td>US</td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-info" data-modal="#myModal" data-href="remote.php">OK</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then you would use the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr > td > a.btn-info').on('click', function() {
        var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('>td:lt(4)'),
            modal = $(this).data('modal');
        $.post( $(this).data('href'), {
                    id: data.eq(0).text(),
                    name: data.eq(1).text(),
                    family_name: data.eq(2).text(),
                    country: data.eq(3).text()
                 }, function( data ) {
                //some processing ... if required
                $(modal).modal('show');
         });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/0d18sjyc/1/)

Comment: Hello @PeterKA, thank you for your complete answer. Unfortunatelly the screen is a little bit darker, but no modal appears. What kind of processing for example do you mean (if required). And by the way how am I suppose to receive the variables in the php? I'm trying just like that: $name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: There's not content in the modal to display, that's why nothing appears. Just to demonstrate, I've commented out the ajax call and invoked modal open. Please update your modal markup per the included demo. In the demo I have included some sample processing your could do once the ajax response returns. And, sure that is the correct way of receiving the data in PHP.

Comment: Hi @PeterKA, wow it works just fine! And what if would like to send the value of a hidden input inside the td? Would be the following code right?
var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('>td><input>:lt(4)'),
How should I do if I have hidden values that doesn't appear in the table just like in my old way that I described above? How can I manage it with jquery? We cannot forget that the data sent will be used in the script and return some new information related to the name of the artist in our example.

Comment: Great! If the data to be sent to the server is in hidden form fields inside the same `td` elements, you would just replace `data.eq(n).text()` with `data.eq(n).find('input[type=hidden]').val()` -- that's it!! :)

Comment: Now I see. Thanks! But what I don't get is how can I use the val in my script. Very simple, let's say that my script in remote.php receives the value of id and multiplies it by 2. In other words I don't want to have the id in the modal, but the result of this multiplication. Sorry my ignorance, but when you say id: data.eq(1).text() that means that id will be sent by post to the data('href') that is equal to remote.php, isn't it? How can I use it then? If I write this:  if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

  echo '<pre>';

  print_r($_POST);

  echo '</pre>';

 }

nothing occurs.

Comment: It sounds like you want to ask a new question; I wouldn't mind answering a new question. When comments get beyond a certain length, it's time to update (**not change**) the current question or ask a new question. Feel free to add an **UPDATE** part to the current question with code samples, so that you can express yourself fully, **OR** just go for a new question altogether. :)

Comment: Hi @PeterKA, you're complete right! I did my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313460/how-to-send-variables-from-hidden-fields-to-a-remote-php-file-and-display-the-re. Would love if you could help.

Comment: Will take a look in a moment. In the meantime, if any of the answers to this question were helpful, feel free to upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<td>`s class so it's easier to select them:

```
<tr>
    <td class="id">01</td>
    <td class="name">John</td>
    <td class="family">Lennon</td>
    <td class="country">UK</td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-info" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="remote.php">OK</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then the click event handler for `btn-info` would be:

```
function showModal(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var fields = ["id", "name", "family", "country" ];
  var post = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    post[fields[i] = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.' + fields[i]).text();
  }
  $.post("remote.php", post, function(html) {
     // display modal, set html here
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello @Marek! Thank you for your answer. How do I have to receive the variables in the php? I'm trying for example with $name = $_POST['name'], but I receive follwoing error message: "Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\remote.php on line 16". I see everything in the modal-body, but the variable. Any idea?