# How to send variables from hidden fields to a remote PHP file and display the result of the script in a Bootstrap modal without refresh using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have following form inside a table that is generate dinamically:

File index.php

```
session_start();

...

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Band</td>
        <td>Indx</td>
        <td>Send</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>Iron Maiden</td>
        <td>95</td>
        <td>
            <form action="remote.php" class="rock" method="POST">
                <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="Bruce">
                <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Iron Maiden">
                <input class="indx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="95">
                <button class ="send" type="submit">SEND<button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Metallica</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>
            <form action="remote.php" class="rock" method="POST">
                <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="James">
                <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Metallica">
                <input class="inx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="90">
                <button class ="send" type="submit">SEND<button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When I click on send it sends the info to the script on remote.php:

File remote.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $band = $_POST['band'];
    $indx = $_POST['indx'];

    $up = $indx * 2;

    $output = '
        <div id="rock-modal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                            Rock Modal
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        The band '.$band.' has an up index of '.$up.'!';
                    </div><!-- /modal-body -->
                </div><!-- /modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /modal-dialog modal-lg -->
        </div><!-- /modal fade in-->';

    $_SESSION['output'] = $output;

    header('Location: index.php');
```

Then index.php is new loaded, but now it opens a modal box with the output from remote.php:

```
<table>
...
</table>

if(isset($output){
    echo $output;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Compare Modal
    $('#rock-modal').modal('show');
</script>
```

But now I would like to do the same, but without page reload, i.e. with jQuery.

I did some research and asked a question with another approach here in StackOverflow ([How to display dynamical content from a remote file in bootstrap modal using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298630/how-to-display-dynamical-content-from-a-remote-file-in-bootstrap-modal-using-php/27299416?noredirect=1#comment43075585_27299416)) to get more information about it. With this valueable info I did the following:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>Iron Maiden</td>
        <td>95</td>
        <td>
            <form action="remote.php" class="rock" method="POST">
                <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="James">
                <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Metallica">
                <input class="inx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="90">
            </form>

            <a class="btn btn-info rock-send" data-modal="#rock-modal" data-href="remote.php">OK</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

$(function() {
    $('.rock-send').on('click', function() {
        var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('>td:lt(3)'),
        modal = $(this).data('modal');
        $.post( $(this).data('href'), {
            name: data.name.text(),
            band: data.band.text(),
            indx: data.indx.text(),
        }, function( data ) {
            $(modal).modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

But somehow it's not working. I'm not sure if the remote.php can read the variables that are sent and give them back. How can I manage it?
It's probably a problem in the javascript. I would appreciate any help!
Thank you in advance.

**== EDIT ==**

Here the code of index.php based on the comments.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Iron Maiden</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>
                <form action="remote.php" class="rock" method="POST">
                    <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="James">
                    <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Metallica">
                    <input class="inx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="90">
                </form>
                <a class="btn btn-info rock-send" data-modal="#rock-modal" data-href="remote.php">OK</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>Metallica</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>
                <form action="remote.php" class="rock" method="POST">
                    <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="James">
                    <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Metallica">
                    <input class="inx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="90">
                </form>
                <a class="btn btn-info rock-send" data-modal="#rock-modal" data-href="remote.php">OK</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.rock-send').on('click', function() {

                var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
                var band = $("input[name='band']").val();
                var indx = $("input[name='indx']").val();
                $.post('remote.php', {
                    name: name,
                    band: band,
                    indx: indx,
                }, function( data ) {
                    $("#rock-modal").html(data);
                    $("#rock-modal").modal('show');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here the complete remote.php

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $band = $_POST['band'];
    $indx = $_POST['indx'];
    $up = $indx * 2;

    $output = '
        <div id="rock-modal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                            Rock Modal
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        The band '.$band.' has an up index of '.$up.'!!!
                    </div><!-- /modal-body -->
                </div><!-- /modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /modal-dialog modal-lg -->
        </div><!-- /modal fade in-->';
    echo $output;
```

But unfortunatelly nothing occurs. :-\

Comment: in remote.php disable the header location. than with firebug or chrome or other check if the $.post return something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pointers to help you solve this:

- The modal markup (HTML) belongs in the main page `index.php`
- If you'd like `remote.php` to return more than one value, return `JSON`
- It's always better to listen for a form's `submit` event instead of a `click` event.
- Be sure to include jQuery, and Bootstrap (js & css)
- **BONUS**: *The processing being performed by the `remote.php` (if that's all it's doing) can actually be performed using JavaScript on the client-side, meaning you do not need to submit the form, and you don't need `remote.php`.*

Your JavaScript should then be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rock').on('submit', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var band = $(this).find('input[name=band]').val(),
            indx = +$(this).find('input[name=indx]').val(),
            up = indx * 2;
        $('#rock-modal').find('.modal-body')
        .text( 'The band ' + band + ' has an up index of ' + up + '!!!' ).end()
        .modal('show');
     });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/oj32pxta/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$(function() {
   $('.rock-send').on('click', function() {

    var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
    var band = $("input[name='band']").val();
    var indx = $("input[name='indx']").val();
    $.post('remote.php', { // dont forget to change the remote url there
        name: name,
        band: band,
        indx: indx,
    }, function( data ) {
        $("#rock-modal").html(data); // data is response from your remote php srcipt
                                     // so set this data to div with id "rock-modal"
        $("#rock-modal").modal('show'); // and show the div with id rock-modal
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello @Pankaj, thank you for your answer. I edit the question and inserted the complete code of the files based on your commentary, but unfortunatelly nothing occurs.

Comment: just check the firebug - console if there is any JS error??

Comment: No error at all! The screen is dark, but no modal window.

Comment: try my edited ans...and also for checking firebug console, right click on your browser and select "Inspect Element" option then one small window will open and go to console option to check any js errors..